# React - How to condition the execution of a function on the state (on the change of state)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a button. If you click it, the text changes (due to setState({})). I want to (only if) the button was clicked and the text changes to pop up a modal component. The function for modal pop up again changes states. The modal should also pop up 1-3 sec after the change. I tried using timeout(function...) but that didn't work. Calling 2 functions only works for text change but not for the modal popup. Any help would be amazing!

```
    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                display: false,
                modal: false
            }
            this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        }
        change() {
            this.setState({
                display: !this.state.display
            })
        };
        toggle() {
            if (this.state.modal == true) {
                this.setState({
                    modal: !this.state.modal
                })
            }
        };

        onClick() {
            this.change()
            this.toggle()

        }
        render() {
            if (this.state.display) {
                return <a onClick={() => { change(); toggle();}}><p>Hello</p> </a>
                    <Modal onClick={this.onClick} status={this.state.modal}/>

            } else {
                return <a onClick={this.onClick}> <p>Bye</p></a>
            }
        }
    }
```

Insight my Modal component:

```
....
    return(
  <div className="modal" data-status={this.props.status}>
....
```

Comment: This line will never be true in the code you posted: `if (this.state.modal == true) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all of this logic must exist inside the component, one place to check for state changes is the [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle function. If I understand your intention correctly, the code could instead look like the following:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            display: false,
            modal: false
        }

        this.toggleDisplay = function(){
          this.setState({
            display: !this.state.display
          });
        }.bind( this );

        this.showModal = function(){
          this.setState( { modal: true } );
        }.bind( this );

        this.hideModal = function(){
          this.setState( { modal: false } );
        }.bind( this );
    }

    componentDidUpdate( prevProps, prevState ){
      // if toggled to display
      if( !prevState.display && this.state.display ){
        if( !this.state.modal ){
          setTimeout( this.showModal, 3000 ); //delay 3 seconds
        }
      }

      // if toggled to not display
      else if( prevState.display && !this.state.display ){
        if( this.state.modal ){
          this.hideModal(); //assuming you don't want to delay hide
        }
      }
    }

    render() {
      const msg = this.state.display ? 'Hello' : 'Bye',
          modal = this.state.modal ? (
            <Modal onClick={this.toggleDisplay} status={this.state.modal}/>
          ) : null;

      return (
        <div>
          <a onClick={this.toggleDisplay}}><p>{msg}</p></a>
          {modal}
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

As I have it, it will be prone to error if state changes occur before the execution of the timer, but I'll leave that problem as an exercise for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!! I forgot to add to my code for the modal component (Now in my edit). Unless I include it, the modal won't pop up but I guess im not including it at the right place, but its: <Modal onClick={this.onClick} status={this.state.modal}/>

Comment: alright, I added that to my answer. Keep in mind that render can only return a single component, so the `<a>` and the `<Modal>` need to be wrapped in a container, such as a `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping!! The problem now is that I cannot close the modal. I tried passing it the hideModal function ( <button onClick={this.props.hideModal} className="close"> insight the modal component) but its not really working. This was the type of modal I tried to implement: https://codepen.io/mike-grifin/pen/bwNQdQ

Comment: since we're passing `hideModal()` to `Modal` as a prop with the name `onClick`, you will need to pass that function to your returned `<div>` in `Modal`. e.g. `<div className='modal' onClick={this.props.onClick}>`

Comment: thanks, it works now-just that I get really weird results. When i open the modal and don't close it butt move the mouse away or scroll that modal starts popping up everywhere

Comment: I think its because Im adding the <App /> in an iteration of items (to eat item) so maybe I cannot do that without getting those weird popups